# terraform aws provider: add default tags in sub-module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using terraform aws provider `default_tags` block in a root module `my_terraform`. That module has a submodule called `my_submodule`, and I would like to have additional default tags in that submodule. I tried this in `my_terraform/my_submodule/main.tf`:

```
provider "aws" {
  default_tags {
    tags = {
      "extra_tag" = "something"
    }
  }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
$ terraform init
Initializing modules...
- my_terraform.my_submodule in my_terraform/my_submodule
There are some problems with the configuration, described below.

The Terraform configuration must be valid before initialization so that
Terraform can determine which modules and providers need to be installed.
╷
│ Error: Module module.my_submodule contains provider configuration
│ 
│ Providers cannot be configured within modules using count, for_each or depends_on.
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: I think the error message is misleading. The error is actually throwing against a provider configuration in a declared module. That pattern is definitely discouraged, but it may also be an error at that vesion.

Answer (score 4):

A workaround is to create a different aliased provider block for each needed tag set and [pass it explicitly](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/providers#passing-providers-explicitly) to each submodule.

```
provider "aws" {
  default_tags {
    tags = {
      default_tag = "asdf"
    }
  }
}
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "foo"
  default_tags {
    tags = {
      default_tag = "asdf"
      extra_tag   = "foo"
    }
  }
}
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "bar"
  default_tags {
    tags = {
      default_tag = "asdf"
      extra_tag   = "bar"
    }
  }
}

module "foo" {
  source = "something"
  providers = {
    aws = aws.foo
  }
}
module "bar" {
  source = "something"
  providers = {
    aws = aws.bar
  }
}
```